# woocommerce_payment_complete not firing on marking order completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

I need to do an action when an order is completed.

I Have tried this:

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
error_log("callback fired");
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete' );
```

But when I use the checkmark to mark the order as completed here in admin orders screen,
[image: mark order complete]

...the hook doesn't fire.
I tried `woocommerce_order_status_changed` too, it does the action when I place the order, but does nothing when i mark the order completed.

But when I mark the order completed, I get the email about completing it.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried `woocommerce_order_status_changed` too, this way:

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete($order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    error_log("$old_status / $new_status \n");
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete', 99, 3 );
```

but it fires on purchasing (I selected bank transfer) and shows: "pending / on-hold", but **not true - see edi2** doesn't fire on manual backend change from "on hold" to "completed". Neither by checkmark nor in single order interface.

**Edit2**
`woocommerce_order_status_changed` and `woocommerce_order_status_completed` works, it only outputed my testing "error" into debug.log, not to error_log for some reason.
The `woocommerce_payment_complete` i used previously doesn't apply to methods like bank transfer, that's why that didn't work. Thanks to @helgatheviking for the quick and right answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the completed order email is triggered by the following:

```
// Triggers for this email
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

as seen [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php#L39) in source.

All "transactional email actions" (ie: actions that trigger the sending of an email) get a `_notification` hook in addition to the normal hook, seen [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L63-L99).

Thus `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` is an additional hook triggered on the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook *if* `woocommerce_order_status_completed` is in the `woocommerce_email_actions` array, which it is by default. To avoid any surprised from the emails, I recommend using the [`woocommerce_order_status_completed`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2390) hook which is fired any time there is an order status change, including from within the admin, see this example:

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    error_log("callback fired");
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete' );
```

Comment: You're right that this is a lazy answer, simply pointing to what I believe is the appropriate hook. I'll try to come up with a basic functioning example.

Comment: I *did* just test it on WC2.6.11, and the function was triggered when marking the order as complete from the Orders overview table and the Edit individual order screen. I looked up the source code for 2.6.11 and [`woocommerce_order_status_completed`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2390) will only fail to fire if the order has no ID, old status equals the new status, or `wp_update_post()` fails.

Comment: Tried to substitute with both `woocommerce_order_status_completed` and `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` with no success, also running WC2.6.11 :/

Comment: I would suggest you disable any other plugins and revert to a default theme. And maybe pepper the [`update_status()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2390) method with more `error_log()` notes to try to figure out what is failing. [`$order->update_status()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.11/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L512) is called when the shop order meta is saved.

Comment: it's strange how some `error_log()`'s outputs go into error_log file and some to debug.log . That's why I didn't see your answer was right.

Comment: I was going to suggest next that you ensure you have `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`  enabled. I am glad that it's working.